# Query to filter out the duplicate and pick the latest

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to filter out duplicates and just get the latest of the form name based on the the higher number, no dates on the table:

Form Name
abc
abc-01
abc-01
abc-02
abc-02
abc-03
def-01
def-02
xyz

And I would like to get this result:

Form Name
abc-03
def-02
xyz

What is the query to filter that out? Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

- the numeric portion is always 2 digits
- the numeric portion never starts with '00' [I'm going to use this as a default for names with no numeric extension]

Setup: (re-using @Glorfindel's code snippet)

```
CREATE TABLE forms (name nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO forms VALUES
('abc'),
('abc-01'),
('abc-01'),
('abc-02'),
('abc-02'),
('abc-03'),
('def-01'),
('def-02'),
('xyz');
```

We start by breaking the names into 2 components, using a default '00' for names that don't have a numeric extension:

```
-- replace the '50' references with the max length of the 'name' column;
-- alternatively replace '50' with any number that's guaranteed to be longer than any 'name' values

select -- if name includes a '-' then strip off the first part, else use the entire name
       substring(name, 1, iif(charindex('-',name) > 0 , charindex('-',name) -1, 50))   as part1,

       -- if name includes a '-' then strip off the numeric component, else use '00' as a default
       iif(charindex('-',name) > 0, substring(name, charindex('-',name) +1, 50), '00') as part2

from   forms
order by 1,2;

part1  part2
=====  =====
abc    00      -- for 'abc' we default part2 = '00'
abc    01
abc    01
abc    02
abc    02
abc    03
def    01
def    02
xyz    00      -- for 'xyz' we default part2 = '00'
```

We'll convert this query to a Common Table Expression (CTE), and then use a basic `max()/group by` construct to find the desired rows ... remembering to ignore the default '00' values when displaying our final results:

NOTE: Alternatively we could use a derived table in place of the CTE.

```
with parts as
(
select substring(name, 1, iif(charindex('-',name) > 0 , charindex('-',name) -1, 50))   as part1,
       iif(charindex('-',name) > 0, substring(name, charindex('-',name) +1, 50), '00') as part2
from   forms
)

select  part1 +

        -- ignore '00' otherwise append a '-' and the numeric portion
        case when max(part2) = '00' then '' else '-' + max(part2) end as 'Form Name'

from parts
group by part1
order by 1;

Form Name
=========
abc-03
def-02
xyz
```

Here's a [SQL Server fiddle](http://rextester.com/BRM16357) for the above.

Answer (score 1):

The query below will probably work; the subquery extracts the highest number after the `-` ('Version') and the outer query concatenates them back into the original format.

```
SELECT CASE Version IS NULL
           WHEN 1 THEN ID
           ELSE CONCAT(ID, '-', Version)
           END
  FROM
(SELECT
  CASE LOCATE('-', name)
           WHEN 0 THEN name
           ELSE SUBSTRING(name, 1, LOCATE('-', name) - 1)
           END AS 'ID',
  MAX(CASE LOCATE('-', name)
           WHEN 0 THEN NULL
           ELSE SUBSTRING(name, LOCATE('-', name) + 1)
           END) AS 'Version'
  FROM forms
    GROUP BY CASE LOCATE('-', name)
           WHEN 0 THEN name
           ELSE SUBSTRING(name, 1, LOCATE('-', name) - 1)
           END) AS subquery
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dE5ozF42c3T9S7xghKvoKG/0) is an online demo.